# How to edit data in main() on button click in QT

Tags: c++, qt, qt5

I have a simple program written with Qt widgets which is supposed to be working with some data, in this case it's a QList of my own class objects. I have a QPushButton inside `mainwindow.ui` which should add a new element to this QList when clicked. The problem is that this QList is only accesible in `main.cpp` where it is declared, and button is inside `mainwindow` and I can't find a way to connect them. Am I doing it wrong? What would be a proper way to do it?

EDIT: some parts of code.

The program has a QTableView called `roomTable` and a QListView called `residentView`. Models for both views are constructed with QLists. The "add" button should add a resident to a selected room. [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/geFwQ.png)

Basically my problem is that I don't know how to store data inside application.

main.cpp

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "addresidentdialog.h"

#include <QApplication>
#include "./ui_mainwindow.h"


int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{

    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    MainWindow w;

    resident bob = resident(QString("Bob"), QString("HRBJWB2421FHFI"), QDate(2022, 05, 10), QDate(2022, 06, 18));
    resident peter = resident(QString("Peter"), QString("GRKBGWJNWKNGJE"), QDate(2022, 05, 10), QDate(2022, 06, 07));
    resident maria  = resident(QString("Maria"), QString("WE23N123EJJFENU"), QDate(2022, 05, 10), QDate(2022, 06, 07));

    room room1 = room(101, 3, 4, 6.7);
    room room2 = room(102, 5, 1, 12);
    room room3 = room(105, 4, 3, 12);

    room1.addResident(bob);
    room2.addResident(peter);
    room3.addResident(maria);

    QList<room> rooms;

    rooms = {room1, room2, room3};

    roomTableModel model = roomTableModel(&rooms);

    w.setRoomTableModel(model);

    w.show();
    return a.exec();
}
```

mainwindow.h

```
#ifndef MAINWINDOW_H
#define MAINWINDOW_H

#include <QMainWindow>
#include "roomtablemodel.h"


QT_BEGIN_NAMESPACE
namespace Ui { class MainWindow; }
QT_END_NAMESPACE

class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    MainWindow(QWidget *parent = nullptr);
    ~MainWindow();
    void setResidentsListModel(residentListModel &model);
    void getSelectedResident();
    void setRoomTableModel(roomTableModel &model);

private slots:
    void on_residentList_activated(const QModelIndex &index);

    void on_roomTable_activated(const QModelIndex &index);

    void on_addResidentButton_clicked();

private:
    Ui::MainWindow *ui;
};

#endif // MAINWINDOW_H
```

mainwindow.cpp

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "./ui_mainwindow.h"

#include "addresidentdialog.h"

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) : QMainWindow(parent)   , ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
    this->setWindowTitle("Hotel Management");
}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
    delete ui;
}


void MainWindow::setResidentsListModel(residentListModel &model){
    ui->residentList->setModel(&model);
}

void MainWindow::setRoomTableModel(roomTableModel &model){
    ui->roomTable->setModel(&model);
}


void MainWindow::on_residentList_activated(const QModelIndex &index)
{
    QModelIndexList indexx = ui->residentList->selectionModel()->selectedRows();
    ui->residentNameLabel->setText( ui->residentList->model()->data(indexx[0], Qt::DisplayRole).toString() );
    ui->residentIdLabel->setText( ui->residentList->model()->data(indexx[0], 1050).toString() );

    ui->dateofEntryLabel->setText(ui->residentList->model()->data(indexx[0], 1060).toString());
    ui->dateofLeaveLabel->setText(ui->residentList->model()->data(indexx[0], 1070).toString());
}
#include "addresidentdialog.h"


void MainWindow::on_roomTable_activated(const QModelIndex &index)
{
    QModelIndexList selection = ui->roomTable->selectionModel()->selectedRows();

    QList<resident> selectedres;
    for ( QModelIndex row : selection){
         QVariant rl = QVariant::fromValue((ui->roomTable->model()->data(row, 1090)));
         selectedres += rl.value<QList<resident>>();
    }


    ui->residentList->setModel(new residentListModel(selectedres));

    if(selection.count() == 1){
        ui->addResidentButton->setEnabled(1);
    }
    else{
        ui->addResidentButton->setEnabled(0);
    }
}


void MainWindow::on_addResidentButton_clicked()
{
    //?????????
}
```

Comment: You need to add all your widgets in the mainwindow and connect them using signal/slots. You should not add any widget in `main.cpp`. Please show a minimum working program so that we can help you.

Comment: ***The problem is that this QList is only accesible in main.cpp where it is declared*** Add  a function to `mainwindow` and pass it as a parameter. With that said its nearly impossible to help you because we don't have your minimal example code. You probably should at least show your `int main()` so we can get some idea what is going on.

Comment: ***Am I doing it wrong?*** I have written Qt code since 2008 at work which is over 1 million lines of Qt code. I rarely have any variables other than the mainwindow and the app declared in `int main()` for a GUI application.  It usually is less than 10 to 15 lines of code depending on if I enable options for HIDPI or replace the default message handler.

Comment: @drescherjm I added a some code, not sure if this is enough, but adding whole project would be a lot of code.

Comment: I will look at this in  in 12 or so hours if no one answered. I have a busy day today..

Comment: Why can’t you move the creation of resident and rooms to the constructor of mainwindow?

Comment: @Aamir idk I thought keeping data inside ui stuff (which mainwindow is) is nott a good practice. But now I think I alomost figured out how to do what I need by making functions inside window and passing pointers.

Comment: @drescherjm ok, nvm, I managed to do it by passing pointer to my QList here and there